# NiFi header index out of range

Tags: schema, apache-nifi

I'm converting pipe delimited text file to parquet. to do so I'm using convert record processor.

Reader-csv reader

writer-ParquetSetWriter.

schema strategy- InferSchema in reader and inherit record schema in writer.

But I'm getting an error in ConvertRecord processor. It says that index for header "ColumnName" is 24 but has only 24 values.

[image]

Comment: Helps to share an example of your header & a row of data. Just from the error I'd assume the index is starting at 0 so value 24=index 23 - but need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input provided, it looks like you have a line that has 25 values because of an improperly delimited set of values. "On index 24, but there are only 24 values" would mean you are on position 25 from an offset of 0.

To debug this, if it's a really big CSV file, you can chain together `SplitRecord` and `ValidateRecord` to try to catch the line that has this problem.

Comment: Found the error record. I'm using combination of Avro schema registry and validate record processor to validate records.